# Get PDF via REST API with header authentication token and show in iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, authentication, iframe

I need to embed a PDF document into html but the document needs a token authentication that is passed in as a header.

```
headers: {'X-Authentication': t}
```

Where `t` is the token that I retrieved after Server authentication.

How can I get the document on the client side and display it in an iframe?

I am using angular to make the REST calls to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this will work but here's how I'd approach it...

Assuming you can get the PDF binary in your app, do so like this

```
$http.get('/path/to/pdf', {
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
        'X-Authentication': t
    },
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        // don't forget to inject $window

        return ($window.URL || $window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(data);
    }
})
```

This will return an `$http` promise (like a normal promise but with `success` and `error` methods) where the data is resolved as a URI you can use in your iframe's `src` attribute. For example...

```
.success(function(uri) {
    $scope.iframeUri = uri;
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Hi Phil the response that i am getting back from the server is {"data":{},"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"responseType":"blob","url":"http://m-files.rangeis.com.au/REST/objects/0/557/latest/files/601/content.aspx","headers":{"Accept":"application/pdf","X-Authentication":"l3oYYmW-d_j7bQQGRtjQLwwtX95JU30GTryswxBpzpjDh-LiKckI0QgNANYJMYpuSYpTmzAtAZuJTUa8acZqhK6_qXwkxOmlzFwiygOAr1RwTUtrYO1wuJVX4yqHcMQ3Ipz5Feo-eauAJ_NplAgSLUpgIQ5YwRdPARwdYebHSc20OSF7TqOBInboN5ZbZ"}},"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: The data is null, hence the uri is blob:null/9224347d-d0d3-44e9-a174-1d32d5b66610.

Comment: Yeah, that's the bit where I mentioned that I assumed you could hit the REST API for the binary PDF data. What do you see in your browser's *Network* console for the response to that request? If it's a bunch of jargon then at least you know the data's coming back. Let me know

Comment: @user1778568 in case the problem was Angular trying to transform the response data through the default means (`angular.fromJson`), I've updated my answer to use a custom response transformer.

Comment: @user1778568 I assume from the *accept* that it worked? If so, that's great!